# How to close the connection after set Transation to Nothing or Commit/Rollback

Tags: vb.net

I develop the DAL class for db operation

```
 Public Sub StartTransaction()
    Dim objConnection As SqlConnection = EstablishConnection()
    objConnection.Open()
    Me.Transaction = objConnection.BeginTransaction()
End Sub

Public Sub CommitTransaction()
    Me.Transaction.Commit()
End Sub

Public Sub RollBackTransaction()
    Me.Transaction.Rollback()
End Sub
```

after start the transaction when we commit or rollback and set transaction object to nothing it dont close the connection attach with this transaction 
how I close the Connection attach to this transaction???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
objConnection.Close()
```

Maybe you need to declare de sqlConnection outside that function so you can reach the variable to close it.

Comment: I want to close the connection which is attach to transaction

Comment: So? You need to close the `SqlConnection` attached to it. Setting transaction to nothing won't close the connection.

Comment: And notice, if you have any doubts between very similar answers that give you the same solution, that you should choose the previous posted one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Public Sub CommitTransaction()
  Me.Transaction.Commit()
  Me.objConnection.Close()
End Sub

Public Sub RollBackTransaction()
  Me.Transaction.Rollback()
  Me.objConnection.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: but objConnection is out of scope

Comment: declare as global in same file